# There is a matrix in a .txt file, how can i get the rows and columns from it? C++

Tags: c++, file, matrix, size

I'm using CodeBlocks.

My file is like this:

```
A: B w w V
B: C w A W
C: D w B X
D: E w C Y
E: F w D Z
```

And i need to get the number of rows and columns, in this case is 4x5. (Letters with `:` don't count)

My first solution is use a variable `counter` an count the dimension of the matrix, but this is not a good solution.

What function can get the size of matrix in a .txt file? Please, any advice, suggestion, is welcome.

Comment: Why is that not a good solution?

Comment: Do you have any approaches? This is not a code-manufacturer-platform.

Comment: @ScottHunter Using a 'counter' i have to open the file twice, one for get the size and another one to do other things. My teacher said that open a file is expensive for the code, and i try to do all the work open the file only once.

Comment: @etalon11  I have my code but is doing other things, i'm stuck in that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the file line by line using getline

```
std::vector<string> lines;
std::string line;
while(std::getlin(fileStream, line)
{
   lines.push_back(line);
}
```

Now you have

```
int rowCount = lines.size();
```

Now for each of the lines you can count the number of elements in it using a string stream;

```
std::istringstream iss (lines[i]);
std::string dummy; //used to munch the initial `a:` part of the string which  you don't need
iss >> dummy;
int numberOfColumns = 0;
char x;
while(iss >> x)
    ++numberOfColumns;
```

Comment: Isn't this *exactly* what was deemed a not good solution by OP?

Comment: @ScottHunter you is right, but reading Armen suggestion some ideas appears in my mind...

Comment: I don't find functions tha solve my problem, but i was worry about open the file twice, so to deal with it i read the file twice, one time to get the lines and columns, then i set to the begin, and another one to do all the work with the file, and that is not so expensive for the code. Unfortunately, that's the only way to have a matrix dimensions in a .txt file, i made a deep search and can't find anything. Thanks guys for help me!